# java-workspace Not Supported

Tags: eclipse-che

Using Eclipse Che 7.0.0-RC-1.0 on OpenShift.io.

Created a java workspace from det default stack (java, tomcat), but gets the message :

This workspace is using old definition format which is not compatible anymore. Please follow the documentation to update the definition of the workspace and benefits from the latest capabilities.

The problem is that the link to the documentation does not address this.

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

**== UPDATE (21.06.2019)**

che.openshift.io has been updated to `7.0.0-RC-1.1` version and now it is possible to start existing Che 6 workspaces again

**== Original Answer**

This is a UX issue we are having on che.openshift.io after update to the `7.0.0-beta-5.0` upstream version. Basically, it is still possible to create and run a brand-new Che 6 workspace, but not possible to start an existing one from the User Dashboard. In reality, one can still run an existing Che 6 workspace by navigating to the workspace links directly from the browser (even though, `Run` / `Open` buttons are disabled navigation to the direct workspace link will start an existing workspace):

[image]

We are going to address this UX issue in the `7.0.0-RC-1.1` release [#13553](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/13553).

"Migrating an old Che 6 workspace to Che 7" docs will be provided by the GA release as part of the - [#12974](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/12974).

The dedicated section in the che.openshift.io FAQ - https://github.com/redhat-developer/rh-che/blob/master/FAQ.adoc#can-not-start-an-existing-che-6-workspace-this-workspace-is-using-old-definition-format-which-is-not-compatible-anymore